# Size of atomic types

Tags: c++

Does the standard say that `sizeof(std::atomic<T>)` is equal to `sizeof(T)`?

(I'm investigating building union of atomic and other types for use across an ABI that ideally should not have STL types. If the sizes are identical then this could work).

Comment: I would say no. Look at `std::atomic<T>::is_lock_free()`. If a lock is required, the handle probably needs to be stored in the `std::atomic<T>` object.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*[atomics.types.generic]/p9*

> Note: The representation of an atomic specialization need not have the same size as its corresponding
>   argument type. Specializations should have the same size whenever possible, as this reduces the effort
>   required to port existing code

No, you can't assume that. It's a *best-effort* endeavor but no guarantees.