# Casting Pointers (int * to std::atomic<int>*)

Tags: c++

First of all thanks to all of you who make this forum so useful for developers.

I've been away from C/C++ programming for some time and now I'm trying to get up to date. While reviewing code I have come across this:

```
volatile int* obj

const volatile std::atomic<int>* ptr_a = (const volatile std::atomic<int>*)obj;
```

I find the conversion of `int *` to `std::atomic<int>*` striking and I'm not quite clear that this is really correct and why, of course at compile time it is valid but the type they point to are different and although the atomic class has overloaded = and T operators I don't see that this has anything to do in this case.

Perhaps I am simply overlooking something elementary.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can give me some information about this.

Edited:

I have seen this conversion in the http_stream.cpp file (line 713) of the Darknet framework:

https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/src/http_stream.cpp

Comment: That is C++ code, not C code

Comment: This code definitely smells bad.

Comment: *"at compile time it is valid"* - it is a `reinterpret_cast` which says nothing about validity, it only tells the compiler to treat the pointer as a pointer to a different type

Comment: Never try to cast away an error unless you know exactly what you are doing. More often than not you'll find you traded a compiler error that you know about for a runtime error you might not find until after weeks of debugging. Whoever wrote this code just shot the code in the head. When casting, start with `static_cast`. The restrictions on its use prevent most of the more egregious misuses.

Comment: No way is this correct. [`atomic_ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_ref) exists for a reason. This bizarre `reinterpret_cast` is definitely UB.

Comment: When casting pointers with an unrestricted cast you're telling the compiler to look at the data differently. It doesn't change the data to make it correct. It's like lying to the compiler and telling it you have a round peg so the peg will fit through the round hole. You can lie all you want, but when the program runs and tries to jam the square peg through the round hole, it still won't fit.

Comment: I have seen this conversion in the http_stream.cpp file (line 713) of the Darknet framework:

https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/src/http_stream.cpp

Comment: @Pep - You might also want to take a look at [Size of atomic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26164094/size-of-atomic-types)

Comment: @Pep: "*I have seen this conversion in the http_stream.cpp file (line 713) of the Darknet framework*" That doesn't make it legit C++.

Comment: @NicolBolas:That's for sure, I don't mean it that way

Answer (score 3):

This is nonsensical C++ code. Using `ptr_a` will almost certainly yield undefined behavior.

It would only not be UB if `obj` were actually a pointer to a `const volatile atomic<int>`. That is, if someone assigned `obj` with code like this:

```
obj = reinterpret_cast<const volatile int*>(new const volatile atomic<int>());
```

But then trying to access `obj` without the cast would be UB.

My guess is that someone used the pre-C++11 trick of using `volatile` to mean "atomic". Then someone else came along and wanted to use valid C++11 code, but they didn't want to change all of the other code (maybe needing compatibility with C, but there were better ways to achieve that). So they did this hackery, and their compiler didn't punish them for it.

It's still nonsense as far as C++ is concerned. Indeed, one should look dubiously at any "atomic" code involving `volatile`.

Comment: As you say if obj was really a pointer to const volatile atomic<int> it would make sense, also if the size of atomic<int> and int were the same (regarding @BoP's comment) it would also work, but it seems not to be the case. What you point out about volatile implying atomic I'm not sure I understand.

To me what is surprising is that it works